# UWP MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync is not returning continent info

Tags: .net, uwp, uwp-maps

I have this code to retrieve the current user's address, I need to get the continent information, but it seems to be returning blank. Any idea what am I doing wrong

```
                var geoPos = await geo.GetGeopositionAsync();
                var s = await Windows.Services.Maps.MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync(geoPos.Coordinate.Point);
                var location = s.Locations.FirstOrDefault();
                if (location != null)
                {
                    countryCode = location.Address.CountryCode;
                }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to get the continent information, but it seems to be returning blank

Yes, the current existing [Windows.Services.Maps.MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Services.Maps.MapLocationFinder#Windows_Services_Maps_MapLocationFinder_FindLocationsAtAsync_Windows_Devices_Geolocation_Geopoint_) API is powered by a REST API Call leveraging Bing Maps Services and HERE Maps Services ("Online Services") providing precise results for the given geo-coordinate.

The Continent information is missing based on current called API(result is encrypted):
[image]

The related team has plan to refine the result in the future. Temporarily I would suggest you checking Here Map API to get such POI information.